# Algorithm for the specific problem

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity

**A problem** : Given a string of number in base $10$ we want an algorithm to calculate the number of numbers, where we replace (only) a single digit to produce a number so that that number is divisible by $3$.

example of input and output:

1. If the input is "23", the algorithm should produce an output $7$ since all the numbers satisfying the condition by replacing only $1$ digit at a time are $03, 21, 24, 27, 33, 63, 93$
2. If the input is "0081", the algorithm should produce an output $11$ since all the numbers satisfying the condition by replacing only $1$ digit at a time are $0021, 0051, 0081, 0084, 0087, 0381, 0681, 0981, 3081, 6081, 9081$

I would like to know if there exists an algorithm that is strictly less than the order of magnitude of $O(n)$, where $n$ is the number of digits of string.

If I use this algorithm, I have an $O(n)$ inference time.

**algorithm**: Loop for changing the string into list of digits, e.g. from "0023" >> [0,0,2,3]. Then, loop for each element in list and replace each with $0$ to $9$ and calculate the sum and check whether it is divisible by $3$ and count for the number that satisfies.

Is it possible to find such number with time $O(1)$ or $O(f)$ for some $f=O(n^\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: (There is a much simpler algorithm for determining the count - start at the test for decimal numbers to be divisible by 9.) Assume that it was possible to ignore the last digit: Can you still provide the correct result?

Comment: @greybeard Do you mean that if the input is "0023"  and so $23\equiv 5 \pmod 9$? By ignoring the last digit we stille have the information that the last digit is $3$ since we are left with "002"? Can you explain more about such algorithm? What is the complexity of it?

Comment: Both above comments/hints are entirely independent. For the first one, `mod` and congruence are right on track. The second one is about the *conceivability* of a (non-parallel) algorithm with a run time that grows slower than the number of digits.

Comment: Can you provide the full algorithm? I don't know how to provide the result after ignoring the last digit and how slower it is?

Comment: `[W. Wongcharoenbhorn doesn't know how to provide the result after ignoring the last digit` greybeard doesn't know how, too. But I think it *obviously impossible*. As there can't be an algorithm inspecting less than $n$ digits, what are the chances of a procedure in time $O(n^\epsilon), 0\le\epsilon\lt1$?